# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in CTBans - Sourcebans

Tags: php

I use CTBans from https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=166080&page=7 and problem is here: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/web/xxx/pages/page.ctbanlist.php on line 74

On 74 line is:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    $row['communityid']=SteamIDToFriendID($row['steamid']);
    if($row['ctbantime'] > 0)
    {
        if($row['ctbantime']<60)
            $row['ctbantime']=$row['ctbantime']." minutes";
        else if($row['ctbantime'] < 3600)
            $row['ctbantime']=round($row['ctbantime']/60, 2)." hours";
        else
            $row['ctbantime']=round($row['ctbantime']/(24*60), 2)." days";
    }
    else
    {
        if($row["active"]==0)
            $row['ctbantime'] = "Expired";
        else
            $row['ctbantime'] = "Never";
    }
    if($row['admin']=="CONSOLE")
        $row["adminname"] = "CONSOLE";
    else
    {
        $admin = $GLOBALS['db']->GetRow("SELECT user FROM sb_admins WHERE authid=\"".$row['admin']."\"");
        $row['adminname'] = $admin["user"];
    }

    if($row['reason'] == "")
    {
        $row['reason'] = "Geen reden opgegeven";
    }

    $data[]=$row;
}
```

What is wrong? When I connect the database, nothing happens (no content). Version SourceBans is 1.4.11
Thank you for helping and answer.

Comment: The problem is that `$query` is not an object. If the call to `mysqli_query` fails, it returns `false` instead of an object -- you need to check for that.

Comment: You need to post the code that creates the query. There's probably a syntax error in the query.

Comment: Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'SM_DB_HOST' (0) in /home/web/xxxxxx/pages/page.ctbanlist.php on line 33

Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/web/xxxxxx/pages/page.ctbanlist.php on line 64

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/web/xxxxxx/pages/page.ctbanlist.php on line 74
--
This is full error on page.

Comment: I connect everything to a database, but then doesn't show up tables on page.

Comment: Looks like `SM_DB_HOST` was just a placeholder, which you're supposed to replace with the actual name of your MySQL database server. Use `localhost` if it's the same machine as the webserver. You probably also need to fill in the username, password, and database name.

Comment: http://banlist.cmgportal.cz/index.php?p=ctbanlist - Tables not shown on page. Why?